# Nodejs async hooks with next callback not working and crashing nodemon

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, async-hooks

Nodejs async hooks with run function having next not getting called and it crashing the nodemon

Here is my async local storage (asyncContext.ts)

```
import { AsyncLocalStorage } from 'async_hooks';

const asyncContext = new AsyncLocalStorage<Map<string, string>>();
export default asyncContext;
```

Request handler middleware

```
import { Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { customAlphabet } from 'nanoid/async';
import { Request } from '../../interfaces/Request';
import asyncLocalStorage from '../asyncContext';

export const requestIdHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.id = await customAlphabet('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 20)();
  const store = new Map<string, string>();
  asyncLocalStorage.run(store, () => {
    store.set('requestId', req.id);
    res.setHeader('X-Request-Id', req.id);
    next();
  });
};
```

As soon as the application run and trigger any api getting following error

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

if i will remove the `asyncLocalStorage.run` function application will working properly.

UPDATE - if runs without nodemon it's working properly
Any help or reference will be very helpful, thanks

Comment: Run without `nodemon` to see what the crash is.

Comment: it's working fine without nodemon, so if create a docker image and run with docker compose it's running without any issue, seems nodemon is the culprit